# Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как передать переменную из JS в JAVA

Tags: javascript, java

У меня есть переменная в JS и переменная в Java, и я не знаю как её передать. Может кто-то знает.

JavaScript:

```
var a = location.href;
```

Java:

```
String a = ;
System.out.println("404: "+a);
```

Comment: Не понятно что и где. Уточните где у вас js а где java и как они связаны

Comment: Может быть у вас WebView в андроиде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью Ajax.
JS находится в браузере клиента, а JAVA на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вопрос задаете некорректно. Я понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Вероятно это 2 разных сервиса (приложения) и они должны общаться между собой посредством протоколов каких-то, часто - это HTTP.
Схема работы, примерно, такая: если у вас JS работает в браузере - JS код(frontend) делает запрос(request) Java-коду(backend) по протоколу HTTP, например методом GET (самое простое), код Java, принял запрос получает значение, обрабатывает и возвращает результат(response). Описывать всё это тут не буду, вам просто, нужно научиться гуглить.

Cоветую проштудировать [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)
в частности [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

А по Java возможны варианты, все зависит от того какую технологию вы хотите использовать,- это и JSP, и JSF, и  Spring гуглите "Java Rest", тут не ответишь - целые книги написаны. Вот, к примеру - [restful](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm)

PS. не обижайте личинку junior-а)